# Javascript Regex vs Java Regex

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have a a regex in Javascript that works great: `/:([\w]+):/g`

I am working on converting my javascript app to java, and I know to escape the \ using \ i.e. `/:([\\w]+):/g`, yet my tests are still returning no match for the string "hello :testsmilie: how are you?"

```
    Pattern smiliePattern = Pattern.compile("/:([\\w]+):/g");
    Matcher m = smiliePattern.matcher(message);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.println(m.group(0));
     }
```

In javascript it returns ":testsmilie:" just fine, so i'm not sure what the difference is. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Java uses a different set of rules than JavaScript, much like PHP vs JavaScript, JS doesnt allow look behinds and other sorts , google the differences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex in java can just be :

```
Pattern.compile(":[^:]+:")
```

Which match `:` followed by one or more no two dots `:` followed by `:`

Or if you want to use `\w` you can use :

```
Pattern.compile(":\\w+:")
```

---

If you note you don't need parenthesis of group `()`, so to get the result you can just use :

```
System.out.println(m.group());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should learn how is made a Javascript regex, because the `/` are the delimiters of the real regex, and `g` is a modifier for *global*

In Java the equivalent is: `:([\\w]+):`, and no need of global flag as you just need to call multiple times `.find()` to get all the matches

---

You should take a look at [*regex101*](https://regex101.com/) which is a good website to test regex